# anti-concentration of polynomials on Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am struggling with identifying the positive constant \epsilon in the following result:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Gaussian variable, $x \sim N(0, I)$. Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$. Then there exists a constant $\kappa$ such that

$Pr[|p(x)| \leq \epsilon \sqrt{Var[p(x)]}] \leq \kappa \epsilon^{\frac{1}{d}}$

In my case, $d = 3$. And I want to pick an $\epsilon$ such that the probability above is bounded by $\frac{1}{3}$, i.e. $\kappa \epsilon^{\frac{1}{d}} \leq \frac{1}{3}$

This follows from Carbery and Wright's paper https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2001/0008/0003/MRL-2001-0008-0003-a001.pdf, 
or simplified by Lovett https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c76b/f92a597a1a2c12feb7f1d2ac79643d2230d3.pdf. But these are going over my head. Please help